# Проблема в коде (if оператор)

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы задать вопрос, я только начал программировать, пытаюсь сделать что-то наподобие калькулятора, пока застрял на операторе if, я хочу с помощью ввода т.е. Сканера, ввести определенный знак и задать его в переменную "znak", чтобы определить что нужно делать, умножать, складывать

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String znak;
    int a,b,result;
    System.out.println("Привет, это калькулятор чисел.\nВведите что вы хотите сделать.");
    System.out.println("Сложение +");
    znak = scan.nextLine();
    if (znak == "+") {
        System.out.println("Вы выбрали сложение\n Введите первое число");

    }

}
```

Comment: Помимо запятых, есть еще один часто используемый знак препинания - точка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй так: `if(znak.equals("+"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `==` сравнивает *ссылки*.
Если вы хотите сравнить два объекта, следует использовать метод `equals`
Не забывайте, если пишете свой собственный класс и захотите сравнивать объекты этого класса, вам следует реализовать свой метод `equals`